# Complex join query with several joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have the following tables

**Product**

```
id                      int(11)         AUTO_INCREMENT                                                  
name                    varchar(254)                                                                     
product_category_id     int(11)
```

A Product belongs to **a**  category in **ProductCategories**. a category has sub category(self join)

```
id                      int(11)         AUTO_INCREMENT                                                  
name                    varchar(254)                                                                     
parent_id               int(11)
```

A Product also has **a** icon stored in **ProductMedia**.

```
id                      int(11)         AUTO_INCREMENT                                                  
url                     varchar(254)                                                  
type                    enum('icon','banner','video')                                                                     
product_id              int(11)
```

What is the most efficient way to get all products with it's associated icon that belong  to a category including products in it's sub category if any.

Example:

```
Product  
1. iphone              - Mobile(category)
2. sIII                - Mobile (category) 
3. liginting connector - Cable(category)
4. iPhone USB charger  - Charger(category)

ProductCategories
1. Mobile   - 0(parent)
2. Cables   - 1(parent)
3. Sim      - 1
4. Shoes    - 0
5. Chargers - 2
```

When i search for Mobile Category it needs to give me all 4 products, under cable it needs to give last 2  but under charger only last one

Comment: how is ProductMedia related to product?

Comment: what do u mean by - "how do i also get products in the child categories there could be upto 2 levels of child categories" ?

Comment: adding to @TilT's point, when you want products belonging to a specific category then the query becomes hierarchy agnostic.

Comment: Forget that I said that. Read the sentence once more and I understand what you're asking for. "get all products with icon for a given category (and all subcategories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use joins for this

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    pc.name,
    pm.url,
    pm.type
FROM Product as p
LEFT JOIN ProductMedia as pm ON pm.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN ProductCategories as pc ON pc.id = p.product_category_id
```

You can do it like this
EDITS :

```
select
  p.name,
  ifnull(pc.Category,pc.name) as Category,
  pm.type
from product as p
  left join (select
           l.id        as id,
           l.name,
           l.parent_id,
           if(r.parent_id <> 0,l.name, CONCAT(l.name,'|',r.name )) as Category
         from productcategories as l
           left join productcategories as r
         on r.id = l.parent_id) as pc
    on pc.id = p.id
  left join productmedia as pm
    on pm.product_id = p.id
```

Output

```
name                        |   Category            |   type 
----------------------------------------------------------------
iphone                      |   Mobile              |   banner 
sIII                        |   Charger|Mobile      |   icon 
iphone liginting connector  |   HeadPhones|Mobile   |   video
```

You can explode Category with php explode

Comment: how do i also get products in the child categories there could be upto 2 levels of child categories

Comment: can you provide some samlpe data

Answer (score 0):

According to what i got from you question you want something like this.

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    m.url,
    m.type
FROM Product as p
LEFT JOIN ProductMedia as m ON m.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN ProductCategories as c ON c.id = p.product_category_id
where c.id='Mobile'
```

Comment: i didn't get what you mean by -"and all subcategories"

Comment: can't you do this with where clause? if not can u show sample data for ProductCategories table?